# Setting 'style' on my user control in xaml replaces the TextBox element with a string 'system.windows.style'

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-style

I have a very basic user control

```
<UserControl x:Class="Framework_Base.UserControls.NumberPicker"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Framework_Base.UserControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="21" d:DesignWidth="60">
    <TextBox Name="ValueTextBox" Width="60" 
             PreviewTextInput="TextBox_PreviewTextInput"
             TextChanged="ValueTextBox_TextChanged"
             DataObject.Pasting="TextBox_Pasting" />
</UserControl>
```

When I add it to my view it's fine, works fine etc.

When I try to add a style like so:

```
<uc:NumberPicker Value="{Binding MyValue}" MinWidth="60">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type uc:NumberPicker}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    </Style>
</uc:NumberPicker>
```

The user control looks like this:

[image]

And I really don't know why, can't find anything on Google searching, but also finding it difficult to know what terms to use in the search.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XAML declaration

```
<uc:NumberPicker ...>
    <Style TargetType="uc:NumberPicker">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    </Style>
</uc:NumberPicker>
```

does not set the `Style` property of the control, but its `Content` property (this is because of a `[System.Windows.Markup.ContentProperty("Content")]` declaration at the ContentControl class declaration).

To set the Style, you need to write

```
<uc:NumberPicker ...>
    <uc:NumberPicker.Style>
        <Style TargetType="uc:NumberPicker">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>
    </uc:NumberPicker.Style>
</uc:NumberPicker>
```

Comment: Frustratingly I was certain I had tried that also to no avail but now it is working as expected.